# What is the Alternative to show "Please wait" window in wpf while the call is non threaded

Tags: wpf

Recently I needed to implement please wait dialog in wpf application. i found below code. it's really good but it always open an window in saprate thread and hold the position. is there any other alter for below code. while my request of code is non threaded.

```
private void NewWindowThread<T,P>(Func<P, T> constructor, P param) where T : Window
{
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
T w = constructor(param);
w.Show();
w.Closed += (sender, e) => w.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
});
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
}
```

to call above method use below lines. where loading window is you window which you want to show at dialog (please wait. windows)

```
   string t = "Please Wait…";
NewWindowThread<LoadingWindow, string>(c => new LoadingWindow(c), t);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocking the ui thread was never a good idea, but it is increasingly more a bad idea.

Windows will tell the user that your app stopped responding. This may incite them to force your appliccations. If you render progress bars, they will lose the animation effects, and they may render incorrect. In WPF the gui animations will stop.

Use background threads for the heavy processing, and if you need to write data back in the objects used by your main thread, marshall them back to the gui thread. `BackgroundWorker` can be useful there.

Answer (score 2):

this might help you out.

```
public partial class Splash : Window
    {
        private static Splash splash = new Splash();

        // To refresh the UI immediately
        private delegate void RefreshDelegate();
        private static void Refresh(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            obj.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render,
                (RefreshDelegate)delegate { });
        }

        public Splash()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static void BeginDisplay()
        {
            splash.Show();
        }

        public static void EndDisplay()
        {
            splash.Close();
        }

        public static void Loading(string test)
        {
            splash.statuslbl.Content = test;
            Refresh(splash.statuslbl);
        }
    }
```

using above code

```
       Splash.BeginDisplay();

// Setting the status to show the application is still loading data
        Splash.Loading("Connecting...");
        // Set to sleep to simulate long running process
        Thread.Sleep(1500);
        Splash.Loading("Retrieving....");
        Thread.Sleep(1500);
        Splash.Loading("Success....");
        Thread.Sleep(1500);
        Splash.EndDisplay();
```